# Putting one image in each box side

Tags: textures, vpython

I want to put for each side of the box (6 sides), one image
face: image1.jpg

left: image2.jpg

right:image3.jpg

top: image4.jpg

bottom:image5.jpg

behind:image6.jpg

Is there a way to do it ?
here is the code I used to get a box with one image

```
from vpython import *
scene.range=1
scene.forward = vector(-1,-.5,-1)
box( color=color.green,
     texture={'file':'images/01.jpg', 'place':['right','sides']} )
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple scheme is to make your own cube out of 6 thin boxes (or quads). I'll mention that you can get much faster and better help in the VPython forum https://groups.google.com/g/vpython-users